# Zend Framework + Doctrine 2: How can I map an existing entry(language) to a new entry (user)?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

I'm using zend framework in combination with doctrine 2.
What I'm currently trying to do is the following:

Saving a user with a related default language, which exists already in the database.

So I have two models: user and language.

The language-attribute of the user model points to the id of the language model via the ManyToOne option of doctrine.

So I use the following code in the user model to do the mapping of the two models:

```
/**
 * @var integer $language
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application_Model_Language", inversedBy="id", cascade={"persist"})
 */
 private $language;
```

The foreign key is updated right in the mysql database.
So everything ok till so far.

The code is the following one:

```
$defaultLanguage = $this->getUserLanguage('en');
$language = new Application_Model_Language();
$language->__set('id', $defaultLanguage);
$language->__set('name', $defaultLanguage);
$user = new Application_Model_User($username, $email, $array['password'], $array['salt']);
$user->__set('language', $language);
$user->save($user);

private function getUserLanguage($defaultLanguage){
    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
    $this->_em = $registry->entitymanager;
    $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = $queryBuilder->add('select', 'l.id')
    ->add('from', 'Application_Model_Language l')
    ->add('where', 'l.name = ?1')
    ->setParameter(1, $defaultLanguage)
    ->getQuery();
    $result = $query->execute();  
    return $result[0]['id'];
}
```

So with the above code, I get first the ID of the language with the name 'en' and afterwards I try to map it with the user, but actually I don't know how exactly.

This doesn't work out. I get an error.

So how can I relate to the language, even it is already in the database (list of all supported languages)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think your annotation is muddled up a bit.
With your ManyToOne annotation you don't need to use inversedBy unless you're wanting a bidirectional relationship between the two entities. And if you did want that you wouldn't use inversedBy="id" because the id field of the language entity is it's primary key, not the user reference.
Take a look at the [documentation for ManyToOne association mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional).